# how to get higher quality or accuracy of own made Haar cascade

Tags: opencv

Could anyone please just roughly tell me what is minimal hit rate, false alarm rate and how do I set width and height for the training purpose. I have already read through documentation on cv2 and also google some of it but in fact it didnt help me much. I have already done my first cascade but it didnt work well and quite horrible. Please just roughly tell me what happen if i change the value of these rate. Im using GUI haar cascade trainer on window. Thanks in advance.

Comment: width and height have to be cosen according to the minimum size you have to detect. Hit rate and false alarm rate have to be chosen per stage, so if your classifier will have 18 stages, and your chosen hitRatew is 0.95, your total hitRate will be about (0.99)^18 = 0.83; for hitRate 0.999 => 0.98. Same for falseAlarmRate. Very important is the training sample and negative sample situation and that's not so easy to explain. You should show some typical training samples from your side.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Width and height have to be according to my training samples (which means the pixels)? For now i have 84 postive images and 456 negative images, is it ok for me to use hitRate 0.995 and 13 stages?

Comment: your training samples will be resizes during training sample generation. But the cascade classifier detection starts with the chosen window size and upsamples the detector afterwards, so the minimum detectable size will be the same as your training size.

Comment: I cant tell whether parameters and samples are ok..You should post your training output (pipe console text to file). In detail you should track the progress between stages. You'll see how the effective hitRate develops and how many negative samples had to be tested before finding a still not covered ( = usable) sample.

Comment: im using GUI cascade trainer. Precalculation time: 1.023

+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+

|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+

|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+

|   3|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+

|   4|        1|     0.81|
+----+---------+---------+

|   5|        1|    0.565|
+----+---------+---------+

|   6|        1|    0.396|
+----+---------+---------+

END>

Comment: could u just simply tell me what does that means?

Comment: Why training with Haar cascade while there are Deep Learning tools nowadays? Haar cascade are completely obselete. For instance, Haar cascade is not rotation invariant.

Comment: HR means hitrate, FA means false alarm, N is the number of primitive classifiers in that single stage. This means it wasnt easy for the training to find . At the beginning of the next stage you should get a value for the ratio between needed negative sample tries per gotten negative samples. This should shrink, but if it is shrinking too fast,  this means your samples might not be diverse enough. Probably you'll have to read about the theory etc. and gain experience with the training yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not an answer, but a hint:

e.g. if you have, after stage 0, this result:

```
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    40000 : 1
Precalculation time: 24.031
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3| 0.995179|   0.0838|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 1 minutes 57 seconds.
```

and for stage 1 you get:

```
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    40000 : 0.124695
Precalculation time: 19.241
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3| 0.999077| 0.142975|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 4 minutes 9 seconds.
```

this means the classifier is quite simple in the beginning. FA of 0.0838 vs. acceptanceRatio    40000 : 0.124695 means, that generalization is ok, so far (0.0838 is close to 0.124695) but there is some gap, so negative samples might be diverse enough. In stage 2, NEG count : acceptanceRatio    `40000 : 0.034703` shows, that generalization is still on a good way. `0.124695 * 0.142975 = 0.01782826762` though .

From my experience, the acceptance ratio is one of the most important things to observe during training, to show you the quality of your training data.